# select tag clicked, jquery doesn't "notice"

Tags: jquery, html-select, onclicklistener

I'm struggling with a problem here. First for the visual code:

```
<input type="radio" name="user_by_list" value="" id="userbylist"/>
<div id="userbylist1">
    <select>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<input type="radio" name="user_by_text" value="" id="userbytext"/>
<div id="userbytext1">
    <input type="text" value=""/>
</div>
```

And this is my jQuery code:

```
$("#userbylist").click(function () {
    $("#userbytext").prop('checked', false); // for unchecking the opposite radiobutton
});
$("#userbytext").click(function () {
    $("#userbylist").prop('checked', false); // for unchecking the opposite radiobutton
});

$("#userbylist1").click(function () { // for clicking the whole div
    $("#userbylist").prop('checked', true); // checking #userbylist radiobutton 
    $("#userbytext").prop('checked', false); // unchecking #userbytext radiobutton
});
$("#userbytext1").click(function () { // for clicking the whole div
    $("#userbytext").prop('checked', true); // checking #userbytext radiobutton
    $("#userbylist").prop('checked', false); // unchecking #userbylist radiobutton
});
```

Now, the problem is, when I click on the select tag to get that div's radiobutton to check, it doesn't work, but when i click the text input area, it works fine. When you click the whole div, it checks and unchecks depending on what function, so that one works alright too.   I've tried setting classes for all options, and also setting an id on the whole `<select>` tag. Any help here?

PS. If you don't understand, although I've tried to do my best explaining the problem, I've set up [an example page](http://craftersinn.net/example.php)

Comment: It works for me on Firefox and Chrome. What browser are you having issues with?

Comment: Are you using IE? In which mode?

Comment: I'm using Chrome too, strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason click is not working is because the option menu pop-up is preventing the up portion of the click to occur on the same element that the down portion occurred on.

As alternatives, .change() will run the function if the selected value changes and .mousedown() will run the function as soon as you mouse down on the option list:

```
    $("#userlist2").change(function () {
      $("#userlist").prop('checked', true);
      $("#usertext").prop('checked', false);
    });

    ...

    <select id="userlist2" name="userlist2">
      <option value="none">Select user</option>
      <option value="none">-----------</option>
      <option value="1">Mike007</option>
      <option value="2">UrbanSurban01</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Worked with mousedown(). Thank you!